# Change name of generated Join table ( Many to Many ) - EF Core 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

How to change name of a join table that EF Core 5 Created ?

for example

```
 public class Food 
    {
        public int FoodId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Ingredients { get; set; }
        public string PhotoPath { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Menu> Menus { get; set; }
    }
```

```
  public class Menu
    {
        public int MenuId { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime MenuDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsPublished { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Food> Foods { get; set; }
    }
```

and the join table for this 2 entities named FoodMenu, I want to change it to something else..

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use one of the [`UsingEntity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.collectioncollectionbuilder.usingentity?view=efcore-5.0) method overloads, for instance [`UsingEntity(Action<EntityTypeBuilder>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.collectioncollectionbuilder.usingentity?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_CollectionCollectionBuilder_UsingEntity_System_Action_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_EntityTypeBuilder__).

Since it is a relationship fluent configuration API, you first need `HasMany` + `WithMany` pair, e.g.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Food>()
    .HasMany(left => left.Menus)
    .WithMany(right => right.Foods)
    .UsingEntity(join => join.ToTable("TheDesiredName"));
```

Comment: @KonradViltersten There is a way - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65779730/manytomany-relation-in-ef-core-fluent-api/65780863#65780863, but I wouldn't call it "clever" :-) Haven't checked it the fresh EFC 6.0 has improved it (there were some plans, not sure if they made it).

Comment: I'll go with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65046246/1525840) which apparently works now that I upgrades from 5.0.0 to 5.0.12 on the EF. Less than clever, indeed. (Well, maybe it is clever but unnecessarily verbose, IM!HO.) But at least working. And thanks for the reply. Appreciate that.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is missing an important part I had to struggle with.

First, you need to install the package

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
```

Then you can add the following in your `OnModelCreating` overridden method

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Food>()
    .HasMany(left => left.Menus)
    .WithMany(right => right.Foods)
    .UsingEntity(join => join.ToTable("NameYouWish"));
```

Comment: if you install EF Core Providers for example Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer then you don't need to install that package

Comment: Correct, but you don't install that by default. I only had EF Core package.

Comment: All `ToTable`, `HasColumnName` etc. fluent APIs require that package, nothing special for many-to-many configuration, hence no need to mention it explicitly.