# Entity Framework Core Many to Many change navigation property names

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have a table called "LogBookSystemUsers" and I want to setup many to many functionality in EF Core 5. I almost have it working but the problem is my ID columns are named `SystemUserId` and `LogBookId` but when EF does the join it tries to use `SystemUserID` and `LogBookID`. This is my current configuration code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SystemUser>()
            .HasMany(x => x.LogBooks)
            .WithMany(x => x.SystemUsers)
            .UsingEntity(x =>
            {
                x.ToTable("LogBookSystemUsers", "LogBooks");
            });
```

I tried this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SystemUser>()
            .HasMany(x => x.LogBooks)
            .WithMany(x => x.SystemUsers)
            .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>("LogBookSystemUsers",
                x => x.HasOne<LogBook>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("LogBookId"),
                x => x.HasOne<SystemUser>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("SystemUserId"),
                x => x.ToTable("LogBookSystemUsers", "LogBooks"));
```

But that just adds two new columns instead of setting the names of the current columns.

This is all database first. I don't want to have to use a class for the many to many table because I do this all over in my project and I don't want a bunch of useless classes floating around. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems this happens if you specify column names that are equal, ignoring case, to the ones EF would use by convention. In SQL Server this throws because object names should be unique irrespective of case. You seem to have a database with case-sensitive names. Just try what happens using f.e. "_Id" in the FK names.

Comment: Yeah I'm using PostgreSQL which I think isn't case sensitive usually but we are using it in a case sensitive way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Interesting bug, consider posting it to EF Core GitHub issue tracker.

By idea what you have tried should do it

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<SystemUser>()
    .HasMany(x => x.LogBooks)
    .WithMany(x => x.SystemUsers)
    .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>("LogBookSystemUsers",
        x => x.HasOne<LogBook>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("LogBookId"),
        x => x.HasOne<SystemUser>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("SystemUserId"),
        x => x.ToTable("LogBookSystemUsers", "LogBooks"));
```

And it works for any other FK property names except the `{RelatedEntity}Id` when related entity PK property is called `ID`.

As workaround until it gets fixed, define explicitly the desired join entity properties **before** configuring the relationship:

```cs
// add this
modelBuilder.SharedTypeEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>("LogBookSystemUsers", builder =>

{
    builder.Property<int>("LogBookId");
    builder.Property<int>("SystemUserId");
});
// same as the original
modelBuilder.Entity<SystemUser>()
    .HasMany(x => x.LogBooks)
    .WithMany(x => x.SystemUsers)
    .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>("LogBookSystemUsers",
        x => x.HasOne<LogBook>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("LogBookId"),
        x => x.HasOne<SystemUser>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("SystemUserId"),
        x => x.ToTable("LogBookSystemUsers", "LogBooks"));
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked great except it told me I needed a key so I had to add a key:

`builder.HasKey("LogBookId", "SystemUserId");`

Comment: this almost works except for one thing: the column order. it seems as if the columns are configured alphabetically, and if that doesn't match the existing DB, you can't change the order in the code, only at the DB level. I thought maybe declaration order would change it, but 5 out of 5 of these are alphabetically ordered and do not change based on declaration order.