# Many to Many relation using fluent api EF Core 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I suppose I have the two entities with many to many relationships, and i am going to use fluent api to resolve this relationship

```
public class Author
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{  
   //Book
    modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasKey(x => x.BookId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().Property(x => x.Title).IsRequired();

    //Author
    modelBuilder.Entity<Author>().HasKey(x => x.AuthorId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Author>().Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired();

    //many to many relationship
    modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
                .HasMany(x => x.Authors)
                .WithMany(x => x.Books);
}
```

Using ef core 5 we dont need to create a new entity.
The problem is in my database now i have a table with the name

> AuthorBook

with two columns

> AuthorsAuthorId and  BooksBookId.

How can change the name of the new table and the name of two columns?
Also is the right way to resolve this relationship?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
                    .HasMany(x => x.Authors)
                    .WithMany(x => x.Books);
```

Comment: I think shadow property will work here.

Answer (score 11):

Changing the Many To Many table name and foreign keys columns is possible with `UsingEntity` in the following way:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{  
   //Book
    modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasKey(x => x.BookId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().Property(x => x.Title).IsRequired();

    //Author
    modelBuilder.Entity<Author>().HasKey(x => x.AuthorId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Author>().Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired();

     modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasMany(
            x => x.Authors).WithMany(x => x.Books).
            UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                "M2MTable",
                b => b.HasOne<Author>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("AuthorId"),
                b => b.HasOne<Book>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("BookId"));
}
```

Result:
[image: DB Data]

It was described on [Entity Framework Community Standup - August 19th 2020 - Many-to-Many in EF Core 5.0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1sxepfIMRM&list=PL1rZQsJPBU2St9-Mz1Kaa7rofciyrwWVx&index=17)

Answer (score 1):

To change the column name:

```
   ...
   b => b.HasOne<Author>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("AuthorId "),
   b => b.HasOne<Book>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("BookId"));
   ...
```

see [Entity Framework Core Many to Many change navigation property names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65043926/entity-framework-core-many-to-many-change-navigation-property-names)