# Seeding data in many-to-many relation if EF Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I have User entity

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Technology> Technologies { get; set; } = new List<Technology>();
}
```

I have Technology entity

```
public class Technology
{
    public int TechnologyId { get; set; }
    public string TitleTechnology { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; } = new List<User>();
}
```

I want to create many-to-many relation, so I have such `OnModelCreating` method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var groupList = new List<Group>
    {
        new Group {GroupId = 1, TitleGroup = ".NET"}
    };

    var technologyList = new List<Technology>
    {
        new Technology {TechnologyId = 1, GroupId = 1, TitleTechnology = ".NET 5"},
        new Technology {TechnologyId = 2, GroupId = 1, TitleTechnology = ".NET Framework 4.8"},
        new Technology {TechnologyId = 3, GroupId = 1, TitleTechnology = "EF 6"},
        new Technology {TechnologyId = 4, GroupId = 1, TitleTechnology = "ASP.NET MVC 5"}
    };

    var userList = new List<User>
    {
        new User
        {
            UserId = 1, FirstName = "Serhii", LastName = "Yurko", Email = "test", Password = "test",
            Technologies = new List<Technology> {technologyList[0], technologyList[1]}
        }
    };

    modelBuilder.Entity<Technology>().HasOne(exp => exp.Group).WithMany(exp => exp.Technologies).HasForeignKey(exp => exp.GroupId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(p => p.Technologies).WithMany(p => p.Users)
        .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("UserTechnology"));

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasData(userList);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().HasData(groupList);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Technology>().HasData(technologyList);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

When I want to create migration I receive such an exception -

> The seed entity for entity type 'User' cannot be added because it has
> the navigation 'Technologies' set. To seed relationships,  add the
> entity seed to 'TechnologyUser (Dictionary<string, object>)' and
> specify the foreign key values {'UsersUserId'}. Consider using
> 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
> involved property values.

How to create proper relations?

Comment: Pls show Group class too

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In EF-core you can't seed navigation properties directly. You have to remove the line `Technologies = ...` from the `User` initialization.

Surprisingly, there's no mention of it any more in the [current documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding) (there used to be), but the junction table can be seeded by its own `HasData` call by extending the `UsingEntity()` call like so:

```cs
.UsingEntity(j => j
    //.ToTable("UserTechnology") <= can be omitted if you agree EF's conventions that will create "TechnologyUser"
    .HasData(new[]
        {
            new { UsersID = 1, TechnologiesID = 1 },
            new { UsersID = 1, TechnologiesID = 2 }
        }
    ));
```

As you see, the hidden junction entity is populated by an anonymous type that has the same property names (+ types) as the table fields. This requires you to know the naming conventions of these foreign key fields (which I hope I guessed right).

You can take this all in your own hands by using the rather clunky full initialization of a junction table, as described in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65046246/861716). That allows you to enforce your own FK property names and use them accordingly in the seeding code.

Answer (score 4):

The `Model seed data` approach has a few known limitations. Most notably, it cannot insert related data by inferring the relations from navigation properties, and you must explicitly add the foreign-key values. For details, see - [Limitations of model seed data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#limitations-of-model-seed-data)

In your case, it is better to go with the `Custom initialization logic` approach, as described here - [Custom initialization logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#custom-initialization-logic)  (don't forget to read the `Warning` carefully).

**An implementation of `Custom initialization logic` approach :**
For the Models -

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Technology> Technologies { get; set; } = new List<Technology>();
}

public class Technology
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TitleTechnology { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; } = new List<User>();
}

public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TitleGroup { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Technology> Technologies { get; set; } = new List<Technology>();
}
```

with the configuration -

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Technology>()
        .HasOne(exp => exp.Group)
        .WithMany(exp => exp.Technologies)
        .HasForeignKey(exp => exp.GroupId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(p => p.Technologies)
        .WithMany(p => p.Users);
}
```

a possible implementation might look like -

```
private static async Task AddEntities(DbCtx dbCtx)
{
    List<Group> groupList;
    if (!dbCtx.Groups.Any())
    {
        groupList = new List<Group>
        {
            new Group { TitleGroup = ".NET"}
        };
        dbCtx.Groups.AddRange(groupList);
    }
    else
    {
        groupList = dbCtx.Groups.ToList();
    }

    List<Technology> technologyList;
    if (!dbCtx.Technologies.Any())
    {
        technologyList = new List<Technology>
        {
            new Technology { Group = groupList[0], TitleTechnology = ".NET 5"},
            new Technology { Group = groupList[0], TitleTechnology = ".NET Framework 4.8"},
            new Technology { Group = groupList[0], TitleTechnology = "EF 6"},
            new Technology { Group = groupList[0], TitleTechnology = "ASP.NET MVC 5"}
        };
        dbCtx.Technologies.AddRange(technologyList);
    }
    else
    {
        technologyList = dbCtx.Technologies.ToList();
    }

    List<User> userList;
    if (!dbCtx.Users.Any())
    {
        userList = new List<User>
        {
            new User
            {
                Name = "Serhii", Technologies = new List<Technology> { technologyList[0], technologyList[1]}
            }
        };
        dbCtx.Users.AddRange(userList);
    }

    await dbCtx.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Its up to you where and how you use it. I myself use it from an `IHost` extension method like -

```
public static async Task GenerateSeedDataAsync(this IHost host)
{
    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var provider = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var dbCtx = provider.GetRequiredService<DbCtx>();
        dbCtx.Database.Migrate();

        await AddEntities(dbCtx);
    }
}
```

so that every time the application starts, we have the option to check whether the database needs seeding, like -

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
    host.GenerateSeedDataAsync().Wait();
    host.Run();
}
```

Comment: Although my answer simply and technically answers the immediate question, I must say in this case (and similar)  I'd also prefer custom seeding. Mainly because this looks like more than simple seeding of some elementary data. It's business data. I'd even take it a step further and use the appointed business methods to create such data. There's probably business logic involved in creating, for example, a user. Therefore, users should *only* be created through that logic. There shouldn't be some shady corner in the data layer where this also happens, bypassing all these rules.

Comment: That means: this approach and the wiring are OK (+1), but I'd call the business logic methods here.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks. I very much appreciate your suggestion, and must agree that it would be a more professional approach.