# EF Core - Unwanted foreign keys being added automatically when I specify my own ones

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I appear to have duplicate foreign keys in my `GroceryItemGroceryStores` many to many join table:  `VeganItemId`, `VeganItemsId`, `EstablishmentId`, `EstablishmentsId`.

I'm only actually using `VeganItemId` and `EstablishmentId` and they are the only ones being added to. It is adding `VeganItemsId` and `EstablishmentsId` columns to my table automatically. How do I tell it not to?:

[image]

This image of my database shows the foreign keys in effect:

[image]

My DatabaseContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<GroceryItem>(gi =>
{
    gi.HasIndex(e => new { e.Brand, e.Name }).IsUnique();
    gi.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    gi.Property(e => e.Tags)
    .HasConversion(
        v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, null),
        v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<GroceryItemTag>>(v, null),
        new ValueComparer<IList<GroceryItemTag>>(
            (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
            c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
            c => (IList<GroceryItemTag>)c.ToList()));

});

modelBuilder.Entity<GroceryStore>(gs =>
{
    gs.HasIndex(gs => gs.PlaceId).IsUnique();

    gs.HasMany(gs => gs.VeganItems)
    .WithMany(vi => vi.Establishments)
    .UsingEntity<GroceryItemGroceryStore>
        (gigs => gigs.HasOne<GroceryItem>().WithMany(),
        gigs => gigs.HasOne<GroceryStore>().WithMany());
});

modelBuilder.Entity<GroceryItemGroceryStore>(gigs =>
{
    gigs.HasIndex(e => new { e.VeganItemId, e.EstablishmentId }).IsUnique();
    gigs.HasKey(e => new { e.VeganItemId, e.EstablishmentId });
});

public DbSet<GroceryItem> GroceryItems { get; set; }
public DbSet<GroceryItemGroceryStore> GroceryItemGroceryStores { get; set; }
public DbSet<GroceryStore> GroceryStores { get; set; }
```

My tables:

```
public class GroceryStore
{   
    [Key]
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PlaceId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Suburb { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string StreetNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GroceryItem> VeganItems { get; set; }

}

public class GroceryItem
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int IsNotVeganCount { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int IsVeganCount { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int RatingsCount { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<GroceryItemTag> Tags { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CurrentRevisionId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GroceryStore> Establishments { get; set; }
}

public class GroceryItemGroceryStore
{
    [Key]
     public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), Required]
    public int VeganItemId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), Required]
    public int EstablishmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual GroceryItem VeganItem { get; set; }
    public virtual GroceryStore Establishment { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int NotInEstablishmentCount { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int InEstablishmentCount { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double Price { get; set; }

}
```

Even adding `.HasForeignKey(o => o.VeganItemId)` like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<GroceryStore>(gs =>
{
    gs.HasIndex(gs => gs.PlaceId).IsUnique();

    gs.HasMany(gs => gs.VeganItems)
    .WithMany(vi => vi.Establishments)
    .UsingEntity<GroceryItemGroceryStore>
        (gigs => gigs.HasOne<GroceryItem>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(o => o.EstablishmentId),
        gigs => gigs.HasOne<GroceryStore>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(o => o.VeganItemId));
});
```

Makes the table have `VeganItemId1` and `EstablishmentId1`:

[image]

EDIT: I have since tried deleting all occurrences of `VeganItemsId` and `EstablishmentsId` from all migration files but when inserting to the database it still thinks it needs to insert `EstablishmentsId`.

Comment: Looks like an Duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65043926/entity-framework-core-many-to-many-change-navigation-property-names

Comment: It’s a bug on EF.

Comment: @Nikolaus Thanks.  Apparently it is fixed in version 5.0.2 of EF Core. I should have mentioned I am on that version.

Comment: @Nikolaus This is not the same issue as the one in the linked post.

Comment: Why are you trying to use composite keys for `GroceryItemGroceryStore` instead of `ForeignKey` ?  I think that is your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In `GroceryItemGroceryStore` change the type of `VeganItemId` and `EstablishmentId` to `Int64` so that they match the type of the corresponding primary keys in `GroceryItem` and `GroceryStore` -

```cs
[Column(Order = 0), Required]
public Int64 VeganItemId { get; set; }       // Key attribute is not needed here
[Column(Order = 1), Required]
public Int64 EstablishmentId { get; set; }   // Key attribute is not needed here
```

2. Modify the configuration for `GroceryStore` to include the navigation properties and to explicitly configure the foreign keys -

```cs
builder.Entity<GroceryStore>(gs =>
{
    gs.HasIndex(gs => gs.PlaceId).IsUnique();

    gs.HasMany(gs => gs.VeganItems)
    .WithMany(vi => vi.Establishments)
    .UsingEntity<GroceryItemGroceryStore>
        (gigs => gigs.HasOne(p => p.VeganItem)
                    .WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.VeganItemId),
        gigs => gigs.HasOne(p => p.Establishment)
                    .WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.EstablishmentId));
});
```

That should fix the duplicate keys issue.

Also, you should remove the following property from `GroceryItemGroceryStore` -

```
[Key]
public Int64 Id { get; set; }
```

since you are configuring a composite primary key through fluent API.

Answer (score 1):

The presence of such FKs is a clear indication of relationship misconfiguration and usually happens when you leave out from the fluent configuration some of the relationship navigation properties, in which case EF maps them to a separate FK relationship with conventional FK property/column names.

In this particular case, the misconfiguration is here

```
gigs => gigs.HasOne<GroceryItem>().WithMany() // (1)
```

and

```
gigs.HasOne<GroceryStore>().WithMany() // (2)
```

because you have left out the navigation properties of `GroceryItemGroceryStore`

```
public virtual GroceryItem VeganItem { get; set; } // (1)
public virtual GroceryStore Establishment { get; set; } // (2)
```

May be they wasn't there initially and you have added them later. But you should always keep the fluent configuration in sync with the model, which in this case of course should be something like

```
gigs => gigs.HasOne(e => e.VeganItem).WithMany()
```

and

```
gigs.HasOne(e => e.Establishment).WithMany()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you have defined `VeganItemId` and `EstablishmentId` as part of athe *composite **Primary Key*** of `GroceryItemGroceryStore`, in conjunction with the  *Artificitial* key of `Id`

> It is not necessary and even counter productive to define a composite key that includes a column that is already unique for all rows in the table, if there is a single column that is unique for all records, and you were going to include it in the primary key, then you should just use that column as the PK.

Your fluent configuration is conflicting with your attribute configuration, I would suggest the following is at least part of the solution:

```
public class GroceryItemGroceryStore
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(VeganItem)), Column(Order = 0), Required]
    public int VeganItemId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Establishment)), Column(Order = 1), Required]
    public int EstablishmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual GroceryItem VeganItem { get; set; }
    public virtual GroceryStore Establishment { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int NotInEstablishmentCount { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int InEstablishmentCount { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double Price { get; set; }

}
```