# Ef core 5 many to many filter

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

This is my query

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<Menu>> GetMenuByRolesAsync(string[] roles)
        {
    var result= await _context.Menus//.Include(o => o.Parent)
                                     .Include(m => m.Childrens)
                                     .ThenInclude(m => m.Childrens)
                                     .Include(m => m.Roles.Where(r => roles.Contains(r.Name)))   --it is not filtering basd on roles                          
                                     .Where(m => m.ParentId == null)
                                     .ToListAsync();
}
```

It is generating below query

```
-- @__roles_0='System.String[]' (DbType = Object)
SELECT m.id, m.icon, m.name, m.parent_id, m.url, t.role_id, t.menu_id, t.id, t.concurrency_stamp, t.name, t.normalized_name
FROM security.menu AS m
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT r.role_id, r.menu_id, r0.id, r0.concurrency_stamp, r0.name, r0.normalized_name
    FROM security.role_menu AS r
    INNER JOIN security.role AS r0 ON r.role_id = r0.id
    WHERE r0.name = ANY (@__roles_0) OR ((r0.name IS NULL) AND (array_position(@__roles_0, NULL) IS NOT NULL))
) AS t ON m.id = t.menu_id
WHERE (m.parent_id IS NULL)
ORDER BY m.id, t.role_id, t.menu_id, t.id
```

This is Many to many configuration
// many to many

```
    builder.HasMany(r => r.Menus)
           .WithMany(r => r.Roles)
           .UsingEntity<RoleMenu>(
              j => j
                  .HasOne(rm => rm.Menu)
                  .WithMany(m => m.RoleMenus)
                  .HasForeignKey(rm => rm.MenuId),
              j => j
                  .HasOne(rm => rm.Role)
                  .WithMany(r => r.RoleMenus)
                  .HasForeignKey(rm => rm.RoleId),
              j =>
              {
                  j.ToTable("role_menu", schema: "security");                                                 
                  j.HasKey(rm => new { rm.RoleId, rm.MenuId });
              });
```

i need to filter menus based on roles..But it is not filtering based on roles..Am getting all the roles..I checked generated query..Please let me know what is the issue..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mixing filtered include with entity filtering.

Filtered include

```cs
.Include(m => m.Roles.Where(r => roles.Contains(r.Name)))
```

just filters the items in the related collection (menu roles in this case).

In order to filter the entity set (menus in this case), you need to replace it with the usual `Where` oparator, which for the desired filtering will be

```cs
.Where(m => m.Roles.Any(r => roles.Contains(r.Name)))
```

Comment: i need one help ..above not filtering child elements..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71274019/ef-core-6-man-to-many-with-not-filtering-chid-entity