# How to modify the join table generated in many-to-many entity relationship in EF Core 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-5.0

In my application there is a many-to-many relationship between two entities - Bill and User. Thus a user can have many bills and a bill can apply to many users.

```
User{
  public string Id{get; set;}
  public ICollection<Bill> Bills {get; set;}
}

Bill{
  public int Id{get; set;}
  public ICollection<User> Users {get; set;}
}
```

Using EF Core 5, I learnt I should be able to ignore the join table of UserBill that contains the IDs of both Entities and a navigational properties to each of the other entities. However, I wish to make sure that no bill occurs twice for a given User.

```
UserBill{
  public string UserId{get; set;}
  public User Payer{get; set;}

  public int BillId{get; set;}
  public Bill Bill {get; set;}
}
```

So I wish to modify the join table as follows:

1. Add unique Constraint to the join table but since the join table is automatically generated by EF Core, I am looking for a way to add this unique constraint to the join table
2. Add other properties to the join table. For instance, I need to add PaymentStatus to the join table to indicate whether the bill has been paid and other properties where necessary

   ```
   UserBill{
   public int Id {get; set;}

   public string UserId{get; set;}
   public User Payer{get; set;}

   public int BillId{get; set;}
   public Bill Bill {get; set;}
   public PaymentStatus Status {get; set;}
   }
   ```

Here I now need to add unique constraint to ensure that there cannot be a multiple occurrence of

> UserId,BillId

Any assistance to get this done will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: it looks like at first that you just need to create the unique constraint but then you seem to want to add one `ID` column to the joining table. So it's very confusing. The problem is interesting at first but then turns out very simple because if you have a declared joining entity type, just configure it directly. In case you don't want that joining entity & no need for `ID` column (which is unusual for a joining entity type), you can take a look at the `UsingEntity` method as answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64919574/change-name-of-generated-join-table-many-to-many-ef-core-5

Comment: the configuration for the joining entity type with `UsingEntity` is not strongly-typed, so here in this case you may need to use the `HasIndex` accepting an array of strings (column names). You need to guess the column names by convention (or explicitly configure the FK to know the exact names), e.g: `join.HasIndex(new[]{ "UserId", "BillId" }).IsUnique()`

Answer (score 0):

`HasIndex` with anonymous type selector allows to create a [composite index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=fluent-api):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserBill>()
    .HasIndex(p => new { p.UserId, p.BillId})
    .IsUnique();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is using `HasKey` and remove `Id` from UserBill

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserBill>()
            .HasKey(p => new {p.UserId, p.BillId});
```